# Micro Frontends with ngrx store and effects

Tags: angular, webpack, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, micro-frontend

I am working on breaking a monolith app into micro frontends on angular 10. The micro frontends reside in separate repositories, i want to use ngrx store and effects in my micro frontends. I cannot do `StoreModule.forRoot()` in my micro frontend's app module. I want to create a root store in the shell app and i want to use the reducers and effects in the micro frontends. I am not using any frameworks like SPA, working with webpack module federation plugin. How do i go about this? Any help will be much appreciated and welcomed.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this? I'm attempting to do something similar

Comment: Hi, have you find any solution to this? I'm trying to use ngrx in the shell application and the micro frontend, but the microfrontend instance overwrite the shell app state

Comment: @vinay G B did you figure this out ?

Comment: @Vinay G B, did you get the answer?